# Physical components of a third-order tensor

Tags: coordinate-systems, tensors

Aris' book [*Vectors, Tensors, and the Basic Equations of Fluid Mechanics*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Vectors_Tensors_and_the_Basic_Equations.html?id=W1tiFsxDedMC) describes how to convert between covariant, contravariant, and physical components of vectors and tensors.

For example, in chapter 7 he defines the covariant metric tensor as:
$$g_{ij} = \sum_k \frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^j},$$
where $y^i$ are Cartesian coordinates and $x^i$ are curvilinear coordinates. The contravariant metric tensor is defined through the identity:
$$g^{ij}g_{jk} = g_{kj}g^{ji} = \delta_i{}^k = \delta^i{}_k.$$

He then uses these metric tensors to convert covariant and contravariant vectors and tensors to their physical components. For example the physical components of $\mathbf{A}$ are denoted by $A(j)$:
$$A(j) = \sqrt{g_{jj}}A^j\qquad \text{(no summation on $j$)}$$

For orthogonal coordinates, where $h_i = \sqrt{g_{ii}}$, the conversion of tensors to physical components is:
$$T(ij) = \frac{h_i}{h_j}T^i{}_j\qquad \text{(no summation on $i$ or $j$)}$$
$$T(ij) = \frac{h_j}{h_i}T_i{}^j\qquad \text{(no summation on $i$ or $j$)}$$
$$T(ij) = h_ih_jT^{ij}\qquad \text{(no summation on $i$ or $j$)}$$
$$T(ij) = \frac{1}{h_ih_j}T_{ij}\qquad \text{(no summation on $i$ or $j$)}$$
He then says that for non-orthogonal coordinates the form is similar to the first one above:
$$T(ij) = \sqrt{\frac{g_{ii}}{g_{jj}}}T^i{}_j\qquad \text{(no summation on $i$ or $j$)}$$
and you can determine the conversion of other tensors by raising/lowering the indices of the tensor on the right-hand-side using the metric tensor, such as:
$$T(ij) = \sum_m\sqrt{\frac{g_{ii}}{g_{jj}}}g^{im}T_{mj}\qquad \text{(no summation on $i$ or $j$)}$$

This explanation is sufficient for me to determine these conversions for all second-order tensors. **How do I determine the physical components of a third-order tensor?**

$$T(ijk) = ?$$

**EDIT:**

Aris provides this description of physical components:

[image: Section 7.41 from Aris' book.]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is meant by "physical components"?

Comment: @Muphrid I've updated the question to include Aris' definition of physical components. Basically if the vector represents velocity, what is the form of the vector with each element having correct units?

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain why this is not a good question so that I can improve it or move it to a more appropriate forum?

Answer (score 1):

As you have already pointed out one can compute the physical component of a contravariant vector using
$$A_{(i)} = h_{(i)} A^i$$
For a covariant vector we have
$$A_{(i)} = h_{(i)} g^{i j} A_j \overset{\text{orthogonal coordinates}}{=} \frac{1}{h_{(i)}} A_i$$
This "transformation" can also be extended to tensor of arbitrary rank
$$ T_{(i_1,..,i_n,j_1,..,j_m)} = \frac{h_{(i_1)}\cdot ... \cdot h_{(i_n)}}{h_{(j_1)}\cdot ... \cdot h_{(j_n)}} {T^{i_1,..,i_n}}_{j_1,..,j_m}$$